# Is there a way to add vertical rotation panning to react-viro 360-image component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to add vertical rotation panning to react-viro camera for a app I've been developing in react-native , in two month I haven't found a way to fix this and it's my first app-developing experience, is it feasible to make it work in any way ?

I've managed to add horizontal rotation and a buggy vertical rotation according to https://github.com/viromedia/viro/issues/103 
they said here that the vertical panning is triggering some kinda buggy issue that I haven't been able to handle.

```
 setPanAndZoom=(gesture,isPanning)=>{

    // this.setState({panning:true});

    let distanceX=gesture.x0-gesture.moveX;
    let normalVectorX=distanceX/this.screenWidth;
    let newAngleX=normalVectorX*this.rotateSensivity;

    let distanceY=gesture.y0-gesture.moveY;
    let normalVectorY=distanceY/this.screenWidth;
    let newAngleY=normalVectorY*this.rotateSensivity;



    if(isPanning){
            this.camera.setNativeProps({
                rotation:[this.currentAngleY+newAngleY,this.currentAngleX+newAngleX,0]
            })
    } else
        {
             this.currentAngleX=this.currentAngleX+newAngleX;
             this.currentAngleY=this.currentAngleY+newAngleY;
    }
}







     this.pan=PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder:()=>{
            return true
        },
        onPanResponderMove:(event,gesture)=>{
            this.setPanAndZoom(gesture,true)
        },
        onPanResponderRelease:(event,gesture)=>{

            this.setPanAndZoom(gesture,false)

        },

    })
```

the vertical rotation seems not to be working perfectly as they said themselves